# Undo mistake in github

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have made a mistake using GitHub and I'm wondering if there is anyway to fix it. When using GitHub, I always branch from my master to a new branch, make my changes and merge back to the master. So if master was 1.0.0, I would create a branch 1.0.1, make changes and merge.

The mistake I made was that when the master was 2.0.1, I branched from it and instead of calling it 2.0.2 I called it 2.0.0, made my changes, committed and pushed without realizing my mistake. The 2.0.0 version now has all of the commits that were included in the master up to 2.0.1 (including the merge of 2.0.1). I was wondering if there is any way I can undo this.

Could I delete my 2.0.0 branch on GitHub and then simply undo all of the changes in my local branch of 2.0.0 so that they no longer contain any of the commits after 2.0.0 and then push it. I know if I do this I also have to redo all changes I have made to 2.0.0 but I can accept that, if it will fix my issue.

Comment: Could you please open `gitk --all` and take a screenshot of the tree, and add it to your question? (wth git-bash)

Comment: From a code standpoint, the names of branches don't actually matter. It might be easier to understand your question (and also your answer) if you talk about the context of the changes you made, rather than the branch names.

Answer (score -1):

In case it ever helps anyone that is silly enough to do what I did I managed to Fix it. I renamed the 2.0.0 branch to 2.0.2 and then deleted the 2.0.0 from my remote repository. I reverted all the changes added to 2.0.0 from when I branched it locally. Once 2.0.0 was back at the right commit (it's merge commit to the master) I pushed it back to the remote repository and everything is now as it should be with all versions in order and my new branch 2.0.2 is the latest branched from my master

Comment: “reverted all the changes” Meaningless. Maybe show actual Git commands instead?